# How to simulate mouse wheel in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I'm not able to simulate the mouse wheel. This code seems to do nothing.

```
cy.get('#elId')
 .trigger('mousemove')
 .trigger('wheel', { deltaY: -10, force: true })
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Unless there is an extremely specific reason I don't see why you can not achieve the same result with ```scrollTo()```

Comment: I want to simulate the movement of the mouse wheel. Even using scrollTo() I get nothing

Answer (score 2):

```
cy.get('#elId').trigger("wheel", { deltaY: -66.666666, wheelDelta: 120, wheelDeltaX: 0, wheelDeltaY: 120, bubbles: true})
```

Try the above